# SQL - Average monthly amount

Tags: sql, average

I have a table with "amount" and "date" columns, and I want to display the average by month.

The table looks like this:

```
amount | date |  
100 | 2017-04-22 20:39:24 |  
300 | 2017-04-25 16:14:08 |  
200 | 2017-04-28 17:51:16 |  
100 | 2017-05-29 05:46:42 |  
100 | 2017-05-08 16:15:13 |  
100 | 2017-05-09 22:06:45 |  
400 | 2017-06-10 10:57:34 |  
500 | 2017-06-11 15:57:14 |    
900 | 2017-06-14 16:02:36 |
```

This is what I have:

```
SELECT AVG(amount) AS avg_amount, date  
FROM table  
GROUP BY date
```

It displays the average by day so it ends up looking exactly the same as the first table but without the hour/minute/second portion, while I want it to look like this:

```
avg_amount | date |  
200 | April |  
100 | May |  
600 | June |
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please do ***not*** deface your question. This is not allowed and any attempts to do this will be reversed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

Check out the [date and time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) functions in MySQL or in PostgreSQL [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function.

Answer (score 0):

I like TOvidiu's answer, but that will only work if you have a single years worth of data. I would suggest

```
SELECT AVG(amount) AS avg_amount, date  
FROM table  
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```